# Let $A \subset B \subset C$ be subrings. If $C$ is finitely generated as an $A$-module, is $B$ finitely generated as an $A$-module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $A \subset B \subset C$ be commutative rings.  Suppose $C$ is a finitely generated $A$-module.  Can we conclude that $B$ is a finitely generated $A$-module?

Thoughts:

- Since $C$ is a finite $A$-algebra, it is an integral $A$-algebra, hence $B$ is an integral $A$-algebra.  Thus, it remains to show that $B$ is finitely generated as an $A$-*algebra*.
- If $A$ is Noetherian, then the main claim is true by Prop 7.8 in Atiyah-MacDonald.  But what if $A$ is not Noetherian?

Note: This is not a homework question.  I'm simply trying to gain a better understanding of how finite generation works.

Comment: Sorry for being dense, can you explain how your second bullet works? If $A$ is Noetherian, in order to conclude using Prop. 7.8, you need the additional condition that $C$ is finitely generated as a $B$-module (or integral over $B$).

Comment: @Prism: If $C$ is finitely generated as an $A$-module, then $C$ is certainly finitely generated as a $B$-module.

Comment: Ah of course! (The same generators will work) Silly me.

Comment: Dear @Benja, your  $C$ is not a finitely generated $A$-module, nor even a finitely generated $A$-algebra.

Comment: I would appreciate it if downvoters could explain the reason for their downvote.